# To upload multiple files in one Net::SFTP::Foreign session in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to upload a set of files to a remote machine in perl using Net::SFTP::Foreign module. The file names are stored in a text file .But all the files are not getting uploaded . Only one file is getting uploaded.

```
#!/usr/local/roadm/bin/perl
# This is compiled with threading support

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
my $count=0;
my %args = (
user     => 'root',
password => 'Ht5h10N2',
more     => '-v',
autodisconnect => 0
);           
print "Starting main program\n";
open(fa ,"<file_list.txt");
my @con =<fa>;
close fa;
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new('hadoop-dev2', %args); 
foreach  (@con)
{
chomp $_;
$sftp->put($_,"$_");

}
```

Comment: How about checking the return status of your function calls? Or running under the debugger?

Comment: I ran it with the debugger. It just says the program terminated use r to restart execution

Comment: Try using the `n` (next) command to single-step through, rather than `r` (run).

Comment: Yup its executing for all the lines in the file as it should , but its not getting transferred to the remote  machine (except the last file)

Comment: Try using the `p` (print) command to print `$_` in the foreach at the end.

Comment: Its printing the filenames , tried it

Comment: And the return status from `$ftp->put` ?

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and paste the contents of `file_list.txt` into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was ,the code was being run on windows with cygwin so one of the major errors were there was thread competition to the single VTY resource and the threads used to get TIMED OUT, So i resolved it using an expect script

Answer (score 2):

You never check the status of your various operations! Did your initial constructor creating`$sftp` work? Was that file you opened really opened? Does that file exist on the remote system?

You must always check the status of your commands in Perl!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use File::Basename;

use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my %args = (
    user     => 'root',
    password => 'Ht5h10N2',
    more     => '-v',
    autodisconnect => 0
);           

# Where is `%args` coming from?
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new('hadoop-dev2', %args);   # Check whether succeeded or failed!
if ( $sftp->error ) {
    die qq(Could not establish the SFTP connection);
}

say "Starting main program";

open my $fh, "<", "file_list.txt"   # Check whether succeeded or failed!
    or die qq(Could not open file "file_list.txt");
}

while ( my $file = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $file;
    $sftp->put( $file, $file ) );   # Check whether succeeded or failed!
    if ( $sftp->error ) {
        warn qq(Could not download file "$file");
        my $remote_files_ref = $sftp->ls();  # Check whether succeeded or failed!
        if ( $sftp->error ) {
            warn qq(Cannot get stat or remote directory.);
        }
        else {
            say qq(List of files in "$remote_dir":);
            for my $remote_file ( @{ $remote_files_ref } ) {
                say "    $remote_file";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note I check whether my `open` worked, whether the constructor for `$sftp` worked, and every time I use a method from `Net::SFTP::Foreign`. For example, I can't download a file that doesn't exist. Maybe it doesn't exist, thus I do a `$sftp->ls` to see when it doesn't work.

You can use `autodie` which is a [pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) for various file commands in Perl, and is a setting you can use for `Net::SFTP::Foreign`. Autodie is nice because it kills your program automatically upon an error, thus turning perl into more of an *exception based* language. This way, if there's an error, and you don't catch it, your program dies.

If you don't want you program to outright fail, you can use `eval` to test whether something worked or not:

```
$sftp->Net::SFTP::Foreign( yadda, yadda, { autodie => 1} ); #Autodie is now turned on:

eval {   # Checks whether the file exists
   $sftp->get( $file, $file );
}
if ( $@ ) {
   warn qq(ERROR: File "$file" is not found!);
} else {
   say qq(Downloaded "$file".);
}
```

---

## Reply

> Theres no error i ran your code, but i still cant upload :( Any help would be appreciated

So, you're saying that `$sftp->get` doesn't download the file, but neither sets `$sftp->error`?

There are a few places in the code where I see that an `undef` is returned, but `sftp->_set_error` isn't be called. Let's just see if `$sftp->get` returns a *true* or *undef*. According to the source code, that's what it should be doing. If it's undef, we'll assume it failed.

```
while ( my $file = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $file;
    if ( not $sftp->put( $file, $file ) ) {  # Check whether succeeded or failed!
        warn qq(Could not download file "$file");
        my $remote_files_ref;
        if ( $remote_files_ref = $sftp->ls() ) {  # Check whether succeeded or failed!
            warn qq(Cannot get stat or remote directory.);
        }
        else {
            say qq(List of files in "$remote_dir":);
            for my $remote_file ( @{ $remote_files_ref } ) {
                say "    $remote_file";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Theres no error  i ran your code, but i still cant upload :( Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Okay, let's forget `sftp->error`. There are a few places in `sub get` in Net::SFTP::Foreign where it doesn't set _error_ before it returns an undef. See my reply appended to my answer

Comment: I get this error
Cannot get stat or remote directory. at t1.pl line 35, <$fh> line 1.
But i have given "/root " as the remote directory ? But yet whats the problem?

Comment: If you can't do an `ls` on the directory, you don't have _execute_ permission on that directory. If you connect to a remote machine as `root`, your user id might not be `0`. Most systems will give you a bogus user id when you connect remotely as root. It's a security feature. So, who owns `/root`? What's the permission on that directory? Is it something like `drwx------`? If so, you don't have permission to read files or to even list the directory contents. This is why you had to check the results of your methods. Try doing an `sftp` directly to the system and see what happens.

Comment: Take a look at the _[verbose](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#more-more_ssh_args)_ and _more_ option in `STP::Net::Foreign. Try running with those and see if you get more details.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my %args = (
    user     => 'root',
    password => 'Ht5h10N2',
    more     => '-v',
    autodisconnect => 0
);            
    
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign ->new('hadoop-dev2', %args);
$sftp->error and die $sftp->error;
$sftp->status or $sftp->error;

my $ls = $sftp->ls('/root') or
    die "Unable to retrieve directory: "
    . $sftp->error;
    print "$_->{filename}\n" for (@$ls);
$sftp->put('/1.pl', '1.pl');
$sftp->put("result.txt", "/root/extranet/result.txt");
 $sftp->disconnect;

Comment: The above code works but when i do it for multiple files it doesnt work and my userid is 0 i dont have drwx----- permission on the directory i have rwx

Comment: Don't use a user ID of `0`! This is the problem you're having. SFTP doesn't by default allow root access via SFTP. It changes your user ID. This is a security issue. If you MUST be root, and MUST access root's directory, reconfigure the SSHD daemon on the server to allow root access.

Comment: By the way, you can see that the program is unreadable when you put it in the comments. Please append it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet that the problem is that you have some full paths to files in your `file_list.txt` and that the paths to the files do not exist on the FTP server. Remember that FTP doesn't create directories for you, so if you have

```
/etc/passwd
```

in your `file_list.txt`, you better have a directory called

```
/etc
```

on your FTP server.

Comment: Hi Mark, No i dont have full paths to my file_list.txt , it has only the file names, iam uploading it into /root
The problems is if i have  
acc1-in
acc4-in
flex-in
then only the flex-in present on the local machine is being put into the remote machine the acc1-in and acc4-in although present on the local machine are not getting uploaded